# Parsing with R huge json with many different keys

Tags: python, r, json

### BACKGROUND

I have a relatively simple but huge (~GB) json file with the following structure

```
[{"a":92,"b":{"2019-01-01T00:00:14":102,"2019-01-01T00:01:15":123,...}},
 {"a":20,"b":{"2019-01-01T01:00:21":104,"2019-01-01T01:01:25":321,...}}]
```

The periods ... in the nested structure indicate that this element has a variable number of entries, up to about 60.

Ultimately I want to be able to make an R-data.frame out of this, with either of the following two structures (option 1 is prefered)

**Option 1**

```
a, Time,                    Value
92, "2019-01-01T00:00:14",   102
92, "2019-01-01T00:01:15",   123
20, "2019-01-01T01:00:21",   104
20, "2019-01-01T01:01:25",   321
```

**Option 2**

```
a,  Time_1,                  Value_1, Time_2,                 Value_2, ...
92, "2019-01-01T00:00:14",   102,    "2019-01-01T00:01:15",   123
20, "2019-01-01T01:00:21",   104,    "2019-01-01T01:01:25",   321
```

It is not so important that the manipulation is done in R. All I care is that the final data is in one of the specified formats.

---

### HOW I HAVE THOUGHT ABOUT IT

I have been able to write an R-program that (with jsonlite and data.table) converts the json into a data.frame with the first structure.
However this technique works with files up to 200MB or so. For bigger files it just takes a prohibitive amount of time.

An approach could be to directly modify the structure of the json object, a bit like one can use xslt to change the structure of xml objects. But I am not aware of such a tool.
Another would be to somehow specify the structure of the json for a parser to extract the information. But I don't know how to do this either.

Besides I just found the R-package jqr, which sounds very promising but I do not quite understand how to use it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jqr/jqr.pdf

---

### PROBLEM

My main problem is that

1. the file is really big
2. the keys of the nested structure are not "unique" because they are timestamps. So a "standard" parser will convert each unique value into a column of a dataframe with the key as columnname and as value the corresponding value, potentially generating a LOT of columns.

Comment: Found this possibly related question, but it is specific to PySpark
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827951/parsing-json-object-with-large-number-of-unique-keys-not-a-list-of-objects-usi